# How would I make a general case accessor for an object in js?

Tags: javascript, accessor

I am trying to make a general case getter/setter for any given object. for example:

```
var obj = {
   a: 1,
   b: "dog",
   c: false
}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'general_case', {
   get: function(attr) { return "unknown attribute "+attr }
})

console.log(obj.a) // should print 1
console.log(obj.d) // should print "unknown attribute d"
```

How would I be able to accomplish this in JavaScript?

Comment: yes! this works great thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

```js
var obj = new Proxy({
   a: 1,
   b: "dog",
   c: false
}, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return prop in target ? target[prop] : "unknown attribute " + prop;
  }
});
console.log(obj.a);
console.log(obj.d);
```